# Hapi passing the reply object through plugin

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I was trying to implement a reply helper through plugin in hapi. The plugin passes the `request` and `reply` object to a helper class. But I think calling `reply.continue()` to return control to hapi changes the reply object. My plugin

```
const replyPlugin = {
  register: function registerReplyHelper(server, options, next) {
    server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {
      replyHelper.setRequest(request);
      replyHelper.setReply(reply);
      reply.continue();
    });

    next();
  }
};
```

Then I'm calling `reply()` from the helper class.

```
this.reply(data);
```

Although this line was executed the request was not ended with response, rather it was stuck. I've tried moving the `setReply(reply)` statement to handler and it worked, but that's not the way I wanted it implemented. Is there any way to make the former implementation work?

**Update**: The `setRequest` and `setReply` methods as well as the constructor of the class are as follows-

```
  constructor() {
    this.request;
    this.reply;
    this.id;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the [request] property of object
   * @param {object} request
   */
  setRequest(request) {
    this.request = request;
    if (request.params.id) {
      this.id = request.params.id;
    } else {
      this.id = null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the [reply] property of object
   * @param {object} reply
   */
  setReply(reply) {
    this.reply = reply;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show what replyHelper setRequest and setReply look like?  You maybe mutating something.

Comment: @simon-p-r I've added the methods.

Comment: Maybe a problem with this binding, try not using an arrow function in handler function.